# Bento Grid Trend: Interactive Dashboards

Tags: design-patterns, dashboard, visual-design, trend

I am exploring the integration of the Bento Grid trend in **interactive dashboards** and seeking insights based on your experiences and knowledge.

**Background**: The "bento box/grid" concept, drawing inspiration from Japanese lunch boxes, has seen a surge in popularity in recent years. This trend gained notable traction following its adoption by Apple, particularly in their Keynote event slides.

[image]

I've observed designers employing this layout for marketing or informational materials, about which I have only positive things to say (I like it too).

However, I would be careful in using it for applications like Dashboards, where the user's goal is not just to view static information, but to interact with it in order to explore relationships, delve deeper into subjects, or simply engage with it on a day-to-day basis.

***Question: Can anyone provide examples or insights on using the 'Bento' design in interactive dashboards? I'm interested in best practices and strategies for balancing its aesthetic vs functionality.***

Example from Dribble, GitHub's promo website:
[image]

Example from Dribble, Dashboard concept:
[image]

Some other example from the internets:
[image]

Comment: The question is very broad and also requesting opinions. Can you edit it in a way  that it is more specific and [follows the rules of the site](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help)?

Comment: @jazZRo thank you for pointing this out. Indeed a subjective question. I've made edits to make it more inline with guide for subjective questions https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here, but this is a quite common pattern that has been around for at least the last 10 years, probably more. Maybe the "bento" name makes it sound new, but if you search for "masonry," you will find thousands of examples, including the dashboard for the most popular website builder, WordPress and the *de facto* standard for analytics, Google Analytics

Comment: @Devin indeed dashboards are made of tiles, and this trend is rather about visual design. However (and this is the core of my ask) while designing a dashboard UI one can get too excited to have a fancy “takoyaki” added in just because “rice with soy sauce” x6 looks boring. A hope this analogy makes sense hehe :)

Answer (score 3):

In short, the bento approach can be visually appealing but is completely impractical for any UI. In long:

### Bento's advantages and disadvantages

To start with fundamentals, bento has the advantage over more traditional grid layouts that it can accommodate a variety of different content dimensions inside it. Key here is *variety*; most "normal" layouts can and do switch from eg. 3-column content to 1-column content (think 3 key numbers above a graph area) but bento uses a wide range of them. Your apple example shows 2x2, 1x4, 1x5, 3x4, 2x4 and 2x3 blocks all composing a bigger box. If this was UI, this allows users to customize their dashboard with very little constraint imposed by you, while arguably being easier to use than freely placeable and resizable windows (alike Multiple Document Interfaces)

It comes with the downside that with all these different shapes and sizes, things are difficult to consume at a glance. Things become much easier if you go for more traditional columns, and your other examples show that too:

[image]

The layout the designers chose here are all fairly traditional 2-columns, where the left column can be subdivided. This greatly improves legibility compared to an arbitrary bento layout. In these examples, the bento approach only is used for the "popular activities" box, which doesn't *need* to be quickly scannable as it just serves as inspiration flavor.

### Major impracticality

Where the bento approach falls apart completely is that you really need to fill all available space. If you take that Apple example again and remove any single block from it, it'd look very weird. Try to reshuffle the elements to form a new uniform rectangle and it may be difficult or impossible to fill any shape of bigger rectangle. Change the shape of the outer rectangle, and it may have too many or too few elements to fill without gaps.

As such, bento cannot easily be adapted to work on arbitrary sized devices (PC, laptop, tablet, phone). You'd have to create rules which stretch and squish certain objects to make them fit (eg convert 2x3 blocks into 2x2 or 2x4 blocks), all while making sure that the content inside of them still looks good. At the same time you have to give up pretty much all experience converting a multi-column desktop layouts to mobile.

### Where to use bento

Given all of the above, I'd strongly recommend avoiding this pattern when designing any real UIs. You're signing up for a world of pain with no real benefit.

Bento is well-suited however for the uses you give examples of: Presentations, marketing materials and mockups.